# How to handle links that open _blank windows in node-webkit properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, window, node-webkit

I'm trying to use `new-win-policy` event to handle link clicks that open new windows. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#new-win-policy

```
win.on('new-win-policy', newWinPolicyHandler);

function newWinPolicyHandler(frame, url, policy) {
    gui.Window.open(url, {
        position: 'center',
        frame: true,
        toolbar: true,
        focus: true
    });

    policy.ignore();
}
```

After click on a link the handler isn't called. I got the message in console:

```
[17120:1029/214512:INFO:CONSOLE(138)] ""Remove zombie callback for window id 1 ev: new-win-policy"", source: window_bindings.js (138)
```

Have no idea what to do...

Comment: Did you figure out the answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for posting your question. Info on doing this seems scarce. I was able to try out some variations based upon your sample. In my case I'm using an iFrame in NWJS, and was able to prevent popups, forcing the URL into the iFrame:

```
win.on('new-win-policy', newWinPolicyHandler);

function newWinPolicyHandler(frame, url, policy) {
    policy.ignore(); //ignore policy first to prevent popup
    $("#Your-iFrameID").attr("src",url); //load popup url into iFrame
}
```