# node-webkit (nwjs): how to apply 'new-win-policy' universally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit, node-webkit

I'm building a kind of site-specific browser using node-webkit and I need to apply policy to any new page that gets loaded as soon as the DOM is ready.

I've gotten as far as understanding that the 'new-win-policy' event is the way to go, and that it has to be set up in the window context of each window (DOM) that loads, per this question/answer:

> [How to handle links that open _blank windows in node-webkit
>   properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650754/how-to-handle-links-that-open-blank-windows-in-node-webkit-properly)

Question is: is that possible from the main.js included in the node-webkit app, or would that have to be done as a modification to the original website? (IOW, do I have to make the website node-webkit aware to pull off what I'm aiming for?)

Answer (score 0):

Eli, I'm just using an iFrame that has an external URL as it's src attribute. The content/server is not controlled by me. I just add an applicable id to the iFrame since I'm using Bootstrap, you could use JQuery and class selector if preferred. Please see my answer, here: [How to handle links that open _blank windows in node-webkit properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650754/how-to-handle-links-that-open-blank-windows-in-node-webkit-properly/28540040#28540040)

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find a working example of 'new-win-policy', I've followed [this suggestion](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/1162) to use jQuery. It worked fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[target=_blank]').on('click', function(){
     require('nw.gui').Shell.openExternal( this.href );
     return false;
  });
});
```

This code can be added in your main.js without needing to modify your original website. In this example, every new page opens in your default web browser.